# How to have string from "a" and increase each time generate a new instance

Tags: java, instance

I have this bit of code here trying to get a string from a, increase every time a new instance is created.

```
class TypeVariable{
    private static int variable_id = 96;
    private static String variable_name;

    public TypeVariable(){
        variable_id++;
        variable_name = String.valueOf((char)variable_id);
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.variable_name;
    }
}
```

but when I do this

```
TypeVariable one = new TypeVariable();
TypeVariable two = new TypeVariable();
TypeVariable three = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(two);
System.out.println(three);
```

the output is:

```
c
c
c
```

instead of:

```
a
b
c
```

what can i do to make it right? thanks

Comment: variable_name shouldn't be static.

Comment: why you use `static` for `variable_id`? and why you use `static` for `variable_name`? the answer is there.

Answer (score 1):

Make `variable_name` non-static, `private String variable_name;`.

The problem with static is that your variable is shared between instances. Hence if you do :

```
TypeVariable one = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(one);
TypeVariable two = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(two);
TypeVariable three = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(three);
```

Then it will work. However, with your previous code, you first instantiated the variables, hence, the constructor did `variable_id++;` each time. Afterwards, you change `variable_name`, since it is shared between instances (static) all instances will see the updated `variable_name`.

Comment: i get a, a, a if I get rid of static

Comment: Sorry i was too fast, `variable_name` should be non-static while `variable_id` must be static. So that the id is increased with every instance but the name is not shared between instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the static field `variable_name` so you always will get the same if you do the printing after creation of the instances.

You probably want to change it to instance field:

```
private String variable_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

is working but you are not considering that variable_name is static too, so if you need that static then consider the time you print it...

```
TypeVariable one = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(one);

TypeVariable two = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(two);

TypeVariable three = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(three);
```

but if you remove the static keyword then you can do:

```
TypeVariable one = new TypeVariable();
TypeVariable two = new TypeVariable();
TypeVariable three = new TypeVariable();
System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(two);
System.out.println(three);
```